# Corpus/data set of English words with syllabic stress information?

Tags: dataset, nlp, corpus

I know this is a long shot, but does anyone know of a dataset of English words that has stress information by syllable?  Something as simple as the following would be fantastic:

```
AARD vark
A ble
a BOUT
ac COUNT
AC id
ad DIC tion
ad VERT ise ment
...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I closest thing I'm aware of is the [CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict). I don't think it explicitly marks the stressed syllable, but it should be a start.

Comment: I would add that it does actually mark primary and secondary lexical stress. See the 1s and 0s on the phones here https://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cmusphinx/trunk/cmudict/cmudict.0.7a .