# Is there a library or web service that provides pronunciations for text?

Tags: nlp, multilingual, text-to-speech

Is there a library or web service that can tell you the pronunciation of a string? I'm thinking of character-based languages, where the pronunciation of the word is not apparent from how it's written.

Comment: Wiktionary!  Just kidding... only sort of.  Lots of words have IPA pronunciations documented, it would just be a matter of parsing them accurately and hoping someone didn't substitute in a curse word when your user looks up a pronunciation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the Wordnik API:

http://developer.wordnik.com/

Free API key will get pronunciations, definitions, and a whole lot more. Easy to use, and the API documentation site is interactive and lets you get your feet wet quickly. Lots of wrappers in various languages.

Disclosure: I work there and love it.

Comment: but it doesn't return a unicode, it returns a text-to-speech notation, people can't read it

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839548/corpus-data-set-of-english-words-with-syllabic-stress-information/2840316#2840316) is a similar question. Research the [CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict).

Answer (score -1):

Google's Text To Speech